# Optimal Solutions for a Blackjack game?

Tags: game-theory

I have the following problem.

> In blackjack, you have 20, and dealers top card is 10. The remaining cards (including dealer's second card)  are A and 10. Your bet is $100. Solve the game (find the value of the game and an optimal strategy).

I was thinking that the optimal strategy here is to say, not to draw a card, since its only 50/50 that the dealer will get the 10 needed to take my money. Both our odds are only 50% so shouldnt it not matter which we choose?

Comment: won't them getting 21 also let them take your money ?

Comment: There are only 2 cards of unknown value in play (one ace and one 10) and one of them is the dealer's down card?

Comment: Yes I think so. The dealer at the moment either has one of the two. Correct me if im wrong here, but if he draws the 10, then its a draw, and if the A, he gets to draw again and will get the 10, and will then get 21 which beats me.

Comment: So maybe its actually better to draw the card so it wont give him a chance?

Comment: Then, there is a 50% chance that the dealer has the A down.  You have already lost, and it does not matter what you do.  And a 50% chance that the dealer has a 10 down.  If you do not hit, you will push.  If you do hit, you will get the A and win.  You might as well hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always draw a card.

If dealer has a $10$, you draw an ace and win.

If dealer has an ace, then he already has $21$, so he beats you if you stay (since $21$ beats $20$), and he beats you if you draw (since you will bust).

If you stay, your expectation is negative since you either tie or lose, each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

If you draw, your expectation is zero, since you either win or lose, each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

Thus, drawing is optimal.